# Accessing class method without calling the class into a variable php

Tags: php, namespaces

Is it possible to use a classes methods without actually calling the class into a variable. I am sure i have seen this somewhere but i'm not sure if i was dreaming.

Take this example:

```
<?php
namespace proj;
class beer{
  public function whichIsBest(){
     return 'Not cheap stuff';
  }
}
```

Include the file start the class but then how can i get to the whishIsBest method without calling the class into a variable first.

```
<?php
include 'beerClass.php';
new \proj\beer();
echo \proj\beer()->whichIsBest
```

Or is this just not possible and I was actually dreaming?

Comment: You probably saw a [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

```
class beer {
public static function whichIsBest() {
 do //
}
}
..

echo beer::whichIsBest();
```